# How to send data with ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using this form:

```
<form class="" method="post" action="">
   <input type="hidden" class="old_name" name="old_name" value="<?php echo $dir . '/' . $file; ?>" />               
   <input  type="text" class="new_name form-control" name="new_name" value="" />
   <input type="submit" class="submitmodal rename btn " value="Rename" />                       
</form>
```

This is my ajax:

```
// RENAME
$(document).on("click", ".rename", function() {
    var old_name = $(this).val(); //getting value of old name
    var new_name = $(".new_name").val(); //getting value of new name

       $.ajax({
            url:"actions.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ old_name:old_name, new_name:new_name },
            success:function(data) {
                $('.echo').html(data);  

            }
       });

});
```

And this the php part `actions.php` to check if he gets the values:

```
if( isset($_POST['new_name']) ){
echo $_POST['old_name'] . '<br />' . $_POST['new_name'];
```

I do not get an echo at all in the `<div class="echo"></div>`. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Add `console.log` in success and check what PHP is returning.

Comment: Why are getting the submit button value? AS per naming convention looks like that you are trying to get old_name which is in the hidden field.

Comment: `console.log;` returns nothing

Comment: I mean to write this `console.log(data);` after this line `success:function(data) { `. if you didn't apply that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tested solution. If not working please specify the problem (share error messages)

**PHP**

```
if( isset($_POST['new_name']) ){
    echo $_POST['old_name'] . ' / ' . $_POST['new_name'];
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" class="old_name" name="old_name" value="This is the Old Name" />
    <input  type="text" class="new_name form-control" name="new_name" value="This is the New Name" />
    <button type="submit" class="rename btn" value="Rename">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){ // this configuration will occur after full html is loaded
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent form default submit action
        var old_name = $(".old_name").val(); //<--use class .old_name
        var new_name = $(".new_name").val();

        $.ajax({
            url:"php/@principal.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ old_name:old_name, new_name:new_name },
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note the result will be displayed in your browser console `console.log(data)`

Comment: Ok This time I tested the solution. Take another look please

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your example

1. The form has no action. It will post back to itself.
2. Your submit handler does not call `e.preventDefault()`
3. You shouldn't class selectors for the form fields and button. Use ids and id selectors. They are meant to be unique.

Here's a fully working example:

```
<?php
$dir = '/somedir/';
$file = 'somefile.txt';
if (isset($_POST['old_name']) && isset($_POST['new_name']) ) {
    echo $_POST['old_name'] . '<br />' . $_POST['new_name'];
    exit();
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="renameForm" method="POST" action="ajax.php">
        <input type="hidden" class="old_name" id="old_name" name="old_name" value="<?php echo $dir . '/' . $file; ?>" />
        <input type="text" class="new_name form-control" id="new_name" name="new_name" value="" />
        <input type="submit" class="submitmodal rename btn " value="Rename" />
    </form>
    <div id="echo">

    </div>
    <script>
        $("#renameForm").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var old_name = $("#old_name").val(); //getting value of old name
            var new_name = $("#new_name").val(); //getting value of new name

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                method: $(this).attr("method"),
                data: {
                    old_name: old_name,
                    new_name: new_name
                }
            }).done(function(response){ //
                $("#echo").html(response);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```